# How enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core, cookies

I had installed **LetsEncrypt**, its work as well
in both of http and https
but I try to Enforce Redirection HTTPS in ASP.NET Core as [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio),
I use  **asp.net core 2.2** and  **iis 10.0.14393.0**
here is my pipeline configuration :

```
 services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
         {

             options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
             options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
         });
        services.AddAuthentication(option =>
        {
           ..

        }).AddCookie(option =>
        {
            option.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Denied";
            option.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            ...


        });
        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>

        {

            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status308PermanentRedirect;
            options.HttpsPort = 443;

        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

and in Configure methode :

```
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = context =>
            {
                context.Context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] =
                        "private, max-age=43200";

                context.Context.Response.Headers["Expires"] =
                        DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30).ToString("R");
            }
        });
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // For GetTypedHeaders, add: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
            context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
                new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
                {
                    Public = true,
                    MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(30)
                };
            context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] =
                new string[] { "Accept-Encoding" };

            await next();
        });
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

but i get this eror in firefox :

> The page isn’t redirecting properly

where am i wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add more specific details to your question. What do you mean exactly by 'The page isn’t redirecting properly' ? Are there any errors in browser network tab; or any exceptions observed in  server console?

Comment: Thanks.no, I  did not get any error in web server or  browser console or network tab

Comment: Try remove `options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status308PermanentRedirect;` and check. Might be this one FF complain about.

Comment: @LGSon you can see i use app.UseHsts();'

Comment: Missed that, comment deleted

Comment: Run Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and view the responses that are returned. "The page isn’t redirecting properly" often indicates a problem such as  you're caught in a redirect loop. A proxy will help you diagnose this.

Comment: @DylanMorley  as you say `The page isn’t redirecting properly" often indicates a problem such as you're caught in a redirect loop, `, yes that's right and in *chrome* I get this error : `too many redirect on this page.` how can I solve this ?

Comment: As mentioned, try running the proxy and inspect the responses. Look a the URL that is being returned as the redirect, does it look right, does it give any hints as to what is causing the problem? Use your debugging tools to inspect the behaviour.